# Two abstracts on the same page

Tags: babel, languages, abstract

So I want to make two different abstracts in different languages on one page but I don't know how to accomplish that. I already tried the option which already is written on this website but it didn't work. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: @naphaneal I already tried that but didn't work, they take one page each

Comment: If you tried this approach, you should be able to give a minimal working example. Only this way, we can see what exactly is the problem in your code. I recommend you to revise your question and add a compilable MWE.

Answer (score 0):

The `abstract` environment is usable trough many instances.

So your problem would be more of a `babel` problem. The doc upon the package is here : https://ctan.org/pkg/babel

Comment: i already have this package for the language but I need to know how to place two abstracts on the same page

Comment: Basically `\begin{abstract}blabla\end{abstract} \begin{abstract{blabla2}\end{abstract}`